# How should I study Topology

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

My semester includes a course in General Topology which includes:

1.Topological spaces

2.Continuous Functions

3.Connectedness

4.Compactness

5.Separation Axioms

6.Product Spaces

7.Complete Metric Spaces

8.Uniform Continuity

9.Baire Category Theorem

I had a  course in Metric Spaces in my previous semester.My instructor asked me to look for a book named Munkres.I bought it but could find it going.Is it the  best book to go along in this subject?What are the ways to make study of TOPOLOGY interesting?

I tried this book for  a week or so but could take out anything from it.Is the problem with the book or I am not able to grasp the subject.Any thoughts of yours would help me.Any other book anyone could recommend?

Comment: Read "Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis" by George Simmons.

Comment: Munkres is a good book for a course in topology, but not necessarily good for independent study.

Comment: @Reasoner: As is usual in such matters, it’s very much a matter of individual taste. I don’t think much of the Simmons at all.

Comment: If you're looking for a book to make topology interesting, I wouldn't look into Munkres.

Comment: then where would you look @anomaly

Comment: @learnmore: Unfortunately, I don't know of a good book on point-set topology. Honestly, the only option might be to accept that Munkres sucks, take the class, and move on to more exciting areas of mathematics as quickly as possible. (My favorite part of Munkres: In discussing Tychonoff's theorem halfway through the book, he mentions that it's the first section that actually requires some creativity or original thinking, rather than just unravelling definitions. Meh. Also, the desultory last section on fundamental groups is awful.)

Comment: what's a good book for self study @MPW

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Sir, I agree to you but I felt Simmons is little down to earth and has a good approach to fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good concise book on point set topology check out [Topology Without Tears](http://www.topologywithouttears.net/) by Sidney A. Morris. The author wrote it so it could be freely distributed online and it has all the basics of point set.

Munkres' book pretty much has EVERYTHING there is to know about basic point set but as MPW said, it's not really good for self-study.  Reasoner's suggestion is also great, but G.F. Simmons' book is much more focused on functional analysis, and is probably not the best "first pass" at topology.

Other than that, you'll probably learn everything you need from your class and a few other resources to move onto other exciting areas of mathematics.